# Menu dropdown não se ajusta a tela

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo, dropdown

Eu tenho um botão dropdown que serve como menu do site, só que ele fica no canto direito do site e acaba saindo da tela, segue print do problema:

[image: Menu fica pra fora da tela, criando barra de rolagem horizontal]

Eu quero que ele fique dentro da tela, sem criar uma barra de rolagem horizontal por causa do menu. O site é responsivo, então no caso ele tem que se ajustar a tela.

Segue código:
html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
                        <button type="button" class="botao" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                            <div class="botao_dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-bars" style="font-size: 1.5em;"></i>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu estilo_dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li class="opcoes">
                                <a href="<?php print base_url(); ?>social">A&ccedil;&otilde;es Sociais</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="segundo_submenu">
                                <a href="<?php print base_url(); ?>blog">Blog</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="segundo_submenu">
                                <a href="<?php print base_url(); ?>contato">Contato</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="segundo_submenu">
                                <a href="<?php print base_url(); ?>educacional">Espa&ccedil;o Educacional</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="segundo_submenu">
                                <a href="<?php print base_url(); ?>eventos">Eventos Sociais</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="segundo_submenu">
                                <a href="<?php print base_url(); ?>galeria_fotos">Galeria de Fotos</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="segundo_submenu">
                                <a href="<?php print base_url(); ?>institucional">Institucional</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a {

  color: $branco;

  font-size: 15px;

  padding: 0.7em;

  padding-left: 1em;

}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {

  color: $laranjado;

  font-size: 15px;

  padding: 0.7em;

  padding-left: 1em;

}

.open>.dropdown-menu {

  width: 20em;

}

.estilo_dropdown {

  @extend .gradiente;

  li {

    color: $laranjado;

  }

}

.estilo_dropdown:hover {

  background-color: $branco!important;

  li {

    color: $laranjado;

  }

}
```

Comment: Bom dia Bernado, poste o código de maneira que possamos **reproduzir o problema**.

Comment: Olá, inseri o código utilizado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alguns pontos que podem estar fazendo o seu layout não funcionar como esperado. Provavelmente somente isso não vai resolver seu problema por completo, mas te ajuda a solucionar.

**posicione o elemento `dropdown-menu` relativo ao elemento `dropdown`**

```
.dropdown{
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown-menu{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px; /* distancia dos botoes */
    right:0;
    width: 90vw; /* vw = viewport width - 90% do tamanho da tela*/
}
```

**Atenção:** vw = viewport width e funciona em IE9 ou superior.